# Combination of Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If I have two linear transformations--for example, a projection and dilation, or rotation and projection--can I simply perform the required operation on each linear transformation individually?

For example:

Let's say I want to project $x=\langle 12,5,1\rangle$ on the $x$-axis and then dilate by $5$.

For the projection, I simply end up with $\langle 12,0,0\rangle$. Then to follow, the dilation would leave me with $x'=\langle 60,0,0\rangle$

Is this correct, or must I combine these steps (similar to a multiple rotations)? My textbook has no reference to this.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can do them individually. The result should always be the same as that of combining the transformations.

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually getting at is the idea of Composition of Linear Transformations.

Formally speaking If we let $\phi:\mathbf{R}^3\to\mathbf{R}^3$ and $\psi:\mathbf{R}^3\to\mathbf{R}^3$ represent projection along the $x-$axis and then dilation by some factor $k\in\mathbf{R}.$

$$\phi(c_1,c_2,c_3) = (c_1,0,0)$$
$$\psi(c_1,c_2,c_3) = k_1(c_1,c_2,c_3)\text{ where }k\in\mathbf{R}$$

then the tranformation that you refer to in your question is $\psi\circ\phi = \psi\phi$. So if we were to compose the above transformations in this manner using the above definitions we have 
$$\psi\phi(c_1,c_2,c_3) = \psi(\psi(c_1,c_2,c_3)) = \psi(c_1,0,0) = k(c_1,0,0)$$

which is exactly would you would get if you were to combine them "individually".

Hope this proved useful to you.